# Transaction signing error

Tags: transactions, javascript, authorization, signing, library

Good morning, everyone
I use EOS UAL to login at frontend, and it works, but there is troubles while signing transaction.
Done signing like in an example 
https://github.com/EOSIO/tropical-example-web-app#transactions
Using scatter for authentication 
and got error in get_required_keys

[image]

[image]

Comment: is scatter unlocked and asking permission before the transaction?

Comment: no, it isn't
there is an error at get_required_keys, but scatter asking for permissions after that request complete successfully
there is something wrong at signatureProvider.getAvailableKeys() stage, it have to return list of available public keys, but returns an empty array